# onMouseOver is not working? but its working as onClick in react

Tags: reactjs

`onmouse` is not working when I hover my mouse on the text in h1 tag, but its printing value in the console when I click on it.

```
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick = (event) => {
    let word = event.target.innerText;
    console.log(word)
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <div className="App">
        <h1 onMouseOver = {this.handleClick}>hover Me</h1>
      </div>
    </div>);
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code works fine, only the "super(props)" part has been deprecated, another trick: when you use Arrow functions you don't need to bind the function in the constructor. This is the complete code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class YourComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state={};
    }

    handleClick = (event) => {
        let word = event.target.innerText;
        console.log(word)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="App">
                    <h1 onMouseOver={this.handleClick}> hover Me  </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default YourComponent;
```

Enjoy ;)